# body-parser doesn't function for express

Tags: node.js, express, npm, body-parser

so, i got that "body-parser is deprecated" error when using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))` and i think i fixed that using
`app.use(express.json)`
`app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` but now my site won't load. I don't know exactly how this works, but this is all my nodejs code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const session = require('express-session')


app.use(express.json)
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.static('static'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("static/showcase.html", { root: __dirname });
});
```

so what's the problem and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call/initialize the `express.json` middleware. Also you can remove the `body-parser` `require` statement and remove it from your dependencies afterwards through `npm uninstall body-parser`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const session = require('express-session')


app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.static('static'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("static/showcase.html", { root: __dirname });
});
```